# Using Google Cloud Platform Storage to store user images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to understand the Google Cloud Platform storage but couldn't really comprehend the language used in the documentation. I wanted to ask if you could use the storage and the APIs to store photos users take within your application and also get the images back if provided with a URL? and even if you can, would it be a safe and reasonable method to do so?

Comment: I am looking for the same. What did you do at the end? Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pretty much use a storage bucket to store any kind of data.

In terms of transferring images from an application to storage buckets, the application must be authorised to write to the bucket.

One option is to use a service account key within the application. A service account is a special account that can be used by an application to authorise to various Google APIs, including the storage API.

There is some more information about service accounts [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) and information [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) about using service account keys. These keys can be used within your application, and allow the application to inherit the permission/scopes assigned to that service account.

In terms of retrieving images using a URL, one possible option would be to use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) which would allow you to give users read or write access to an object (in your case images) in a bucket for a given amount of time.

Access to bucket objects can also be controlled with ACL (Access Control Lists). If you're happy for you images to be available publicly (i.e. accessible to everybody), it's possible to set an ACL with 'Reader' access for AllUsers. 
More information on this can be [found here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists).

Should you decide to make the images available publically, the URL format to retrive the object/image from the bucket would be:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

EDIT:

In relation to using an interface to upload the files before the files land in the bucket, one option would be to have a instance with an external IP address (or multiple instances behind a Load Balancer) where the images are initially uploaded. You could mount Cloud Storage to this instance using [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse), so that uploaded files are easily transferred to the bucket. In terms of databases you have the option of manually installing your database on a Compute Engine instance, or using a fully managed database service such as Cloud SQL.

Comment: I want to interface with a webAPI first before the storage bucket. So that the client sends the image to the webAPI which then stores the image in the storage bucket and a reference to the image in a database. Is this a viable option?